# ¿Como consigo quitar el problema de jump to case label?

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un programa y a la hora de usar el case me sale un error de jump  to case label

En el caso 1 no ocurre nada pero a la hora de escribir case 2 : y el deafult ya me sale el error de jump to case label y he intentado de muchas formas como poner llaves a todos los cases pero sigue sin sfuncionar

````
    char mandato[MAX_CARACTERES + 1];
    switch (argc)
    {
    case 1 :
        char *comando = new char;
        while (true) {
            cout << "$ ";
            read(comando, 255);
            if (strcmp(comando, "salir") == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            ejecutarvarios(comando);
        }
        break;
    case 2:
    {
         ifstream entrada;
        entrada.open(argv[1]); // abre el fichero y lo asocia a entrada
        if (entrada.fail())
        { // comprueba que se ha abierto correctamente
            cerr << "No puede abrirse el archivo " << argv[1] << endl;
            exit(2);
        }
        else
        {
            // lee una línea de mandato del fichero
            entrada.getline(mandato, MAX_CARACTERES, '\n');
            while (!entrada.eof() && strcmp(comando, "salir") != 0)
            { // Mientras no termine el fichero ni el mandato sea salir
                // Ejecutar la línea de mandato en otro proceso usando la función ejecutar
                ejecutarvarios(mandato);
                // lee otra línea de mandato del fichero
                entrada.getline(mandato, MAX_CARACTERES, '\n');
            }
            entrada.close(); // cierra el fichero
        }
        break;
    }
    
    default:
        cerr << "Número de argumentos incorrecto" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
} ```
````

Comment: La respuesta que dejaron es correcta y esta bien descrita. Tu error esta en tu primer Case, no cuenta con un bloque de llaves por lo que te arroja ese error. Verifica siempre las llaves y la estructura de cada ciclo, consulta o condicional.